# makeindex and restricted \write18

Tags: pdftex, nomenclature, shell-escape

I use the `nomenclature` package to create nomenclature sections for my papers. I haven't done a paper in a while with a nomenclature, but today it is not working.

In order to use the `nomenclature` package, I need to run `makeindex` and then rerun my LaTeX file. I normally have the following at the very first line of my LaTeX file and everything works fine automatically pretty much.

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex "paper".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "paper".nls}
```

Today it isn't working though. It seems as though `\write18` restricted mode is the problem. It's possible something changed with TeX Live since I last wrote a paper with a nomenclature section when I upgrade my operating system at some point.

I can get `bibtex` to run with `\write18`. Any reason why `makeindex` would not work? I thought it should be a safe program.

If I run with `--shell-escape`, everything works fine, but I don't want to do that because restricted mode was created for a reason. I can also run the `makeindex` command manually in a bash shell and everything works fine, but I am using kile and don't want to have to run another command all the time.

Simplest example file I can create:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex "paper".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "paper".nls}
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature
    some text
    \nomenclature{$symbol$}{description}
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex paper.tex` produces no nomenclature. Running `pdflatex --shell-escape paper.tex` produces a nomenclature. When testing, make sure you delete all the extra files in the directory after running with `--shell-escape` or change the symbol name because you may think the problem is solved when in fact the `makeindex` command was just run by your last test.

How can I see what commands are allowed in restricted mode? If I run `kpsewhich --var-value shell_escape_commands` in bash, it returns 'bibtex,bibtex8,kpsewhich,makeindex,mpost,repstopdf,'. So, It seems as if makeindex should work.

I am using `pdflatex` on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Answer (score 4):

If I run the example, I get

```
runsystem(makeindex "donom".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "donom".nls)...quotation error in system command.
```

in the log file; tested with MacTeX/TeX Live 2014 on Mac OS X and TeX Live/Debian 2013 on a Debian box.

On the other hand, if I change the line into

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex "\jobname.nlo" -s nomencl.ist -o "\jobname.nls"}
```

then the command is executed.

Note that using `\jobname` instead of the actual file name allows for reusing the code. Also, I'd use

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o "\jobname.nls" "\jobname.nlo"}
```

because this is a more common syntax (however, `makeindex` accepts options also after the file name).

There is also a different strategy, that is, using `arara`:

```
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature
    some text
    \nomenclature{$symbol$}{description}
\end{document}
```

If you run the command line

```
arara -v <filename>
```

you'll achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the unusual file name quotation (i.e. "paper".nlo and "paper".nls) became an issue for restricted \write18. I don't know why I had used that in the past but it must have been some quirk related to makeindex that required it. That quirk seems to be fixed now. So, if I change to

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex paper.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o paper.nls}
```

everything works as expected.